# How do I parse the HTML from the Lexical editorState without an extra Lexical editor

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, text-editor, lexicaljs

I have a posts system and when someone submits a post I am saving the `editorState` as a JSON string in a Postgres database.

Then, when I need to show the HTML, I am using a custom hook which loads an auxiliary editor just to obtain the HTML.

Is this the proper way? Looks to me a bit overengineering 
I don't want to load other editor, and render it too just to obtain the HTML.

Any idea of how to improve this or suggestion for a different approach?

The render post component:

```
export const PostDetails = () => {
  const postSlug = useParam("postSlug", "string")
  const [postDetails] = useQuery(getPostPageDetails, { slug: postSlug })

  const { html, AuxEditor } = useGetHtmlFromState(postDetails.content as unknown as EditorState)

  return (
    <>
      <AuxEditor />
      <Text dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />
    </>
  )
}
```

The hook to get the HTML useGetHtmlFromState (it uses the same config as the input)

```
export const useGetHtmlFromState = (state: EditorState) => {
  const [html, setHtml] = useState("")

  function MyCustomStateToHtmlPlugin() {
    const [editor] = useLexicalComposerContext()
    editor.update(() => {
      const html = $generateHtmlFromNodes(editor, null)
      setHtml(html)
    })

    return null
  }

  const AuxEditor = () => {
    return (
      <LexicalComposer
        initialConfig={{
          namespace: "MyEditor",
          onError: console.error,
          editorState: state,
          theme: exampleTheme,
          nodes: [
            HeadingNode,
            ListNode,
            ListItemNode,
            QuoteNode,
            CodeNode,
            CodeHighlightNode,
            TableNode,
            TableCellNode,
            TableRowNode,
            AutoLinkNode,
            LinkNode,
          ],
        }}
      >
        <MyCustomStateToHtmlPlugin />
      </LexicalComposer>
    )
  }

  return { html, AuxEditor }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you have is a creative way to turn `SerializedEditorState` into HTML. You could experiment with [@lexical/headless](https://lexical.dev/docs/packages/lexical-headless), but it's essentially the same approach. Alternatively, there are a couple of other ways to solve the underlying problem of displaying saved state.

(1) You can generate the HTML up front and save it to the DB alongside the lexical state. It's a bit duplicative, but it works for the "write once, read many times" use case you've described.

(2) You can use a [read-only](https://lexical.dev/docs/concepts/read-only) lexical editor to display the saved state instead of converting it into HTML. You can configure the editor with a different theme if you need more control over the styling of specific elements.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Monty 

I am not very fan of storing duplicate data in the DB unless there is no other option.
 I haven't tried the read-only editor yet. I am parsing some html <span> mentions to <a> tags  can I do that in the readOnly editor? 
`export const parseSpanMentionsHtmlToHtml = (html: string) => {
  const regex = /<span data-lexical-mention="true">(\w+)<\/span>/g
  return html.replace(regex, (_, mention) => { return \`<a href="/${mention}" >@${mention}</a>\` })}`

Comment: If you used the read-only editor then you'd likely bypass all HTML parsing. Instead, you'd feed the read-only editor your saved lexical JSON and it would display just like your post editor. If you want to change styling then you'd configure the editor with a custom `theme`.

Comment: If you want to transform mention nodes into links then I would suggest using `registerNodeTransform` in the read-only editor to swap them as soon as they're created.

Comment: That sounds like the proper way to achieve my purpose. I will give it a try at some point and let you know how it goes. Thanks @Monty 

Comment: @reymon359 could you, please, share your experience with it? I'm wondering what solution did you use?

Comment: Velidan I ended up using Monty's solution :)

Comment: @reymon359  thank you for your answer. So could you, please, tell which one? Lexical instance with the `readonly` mode? or did you generate the html and save it in DB? I personally think that the `readonly` option is a better but I'm interested in your practical feedback?

Comment: You are right, the readonly mode 

Comment: @reymon359 thank you! I'm giong to do the same because I just don't see any other appropriate alternatives. Hovewer, I'm thinking about some performance when we have a long list. Definitely need to add some perf improving features like pagination or windowing